# Undefined variable but it's already declared Laravel

Tags: laravel, parameters, builder

I'm having some problems with my website.

Lately, I've been working on a "filtering page" where the user selects/writes a character, and then it searches X data with that character (From A-Z and 0-9). The character **can be optional**.

This is my **getAffiliates** function:

```
public static function getAffiliates($community_id, $character) {
    if (!empty($character)) {
        $character = strval($character);
        if (is_numeric($character)) {
            $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->whereHas('user', function($q) {
                $q->where('name', 'regexp', '^[0-9]+');
            })->get();
        } else {
            $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->whereHas('user', function($q) {
                $q->where('name', 'like', $character.'%');
            })->get();
        }
    } else {
        $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->take(50)->get();
    }
    return $users;
}
```

What this code does is, given an X **$community_id**, and an X **$character**, it will determine whether **$character** is integer or not. Then, it will do a query to the database and it will retrieve a collection conditioned on the given parameters. Basically, the query looks for a value where the initial character equals my **$character** parameter.

What I don't know is, **why am I getting the "undefined variable $character" error**?

[image]

My controller's code is this (**Notice the parameter can be null**):

[image]

**Can someone explain what is actually wrong?**

UPDATE With the Full Trace Error

[image]

Comment: Can you shere complete error detail?

Comment: Updated with a picture, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use variable top of where has function. to access it.

```
public static function getAffiliates($community_id, $character) {
if (!empty($character)) {
    $character = strval($character);
    if (is_numeric($character)) {
        $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->whereHas('user', function($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'regexp', '^[0-9]+');
        })->get();
    } else {
        $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($character) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', $character.'%');
        })->get();
    }
} else {
    $users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)->take(50)->get();
}
return $users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$character` variable is defined outside the scope of where it's being used.

You can use the `use` keyword to bring the variable into the closure's scope like this:

```
$users = UserCommunity::with('user')->where('community_id', $community_id)
     ->whereHas('user', function($q) use($character) { // <-- do this
          $q->where('name', 'like', $character.'%');
      })->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot that very important use($character)  Solved